# Как правильно передавать retrofit response в otto event?

Tags: java, android

Имеется событие:

```
@Subscribe
    public void onGetAuthEvent(GetAuthEvent getAuthEvent) {

        String email = (getAuthEvent.getEmail());
        String password = (getAuthEvent.getPassword());

        ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Account> call = apiService.auth(email, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Account>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Account> call, Response<Account> response) {
                mBus.post(new SendAuthEvent(response));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Account> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("OnFailure:", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Как должна выглядеть модель для получения значения ответа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно сам Response отдавать в событии, достаточно передать тело ответа.
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

```
mBus.post(new SendAuthEvent(response.body()));
```